# Disabling animation of the Wifi connection icon

Tags: notification-bar

On Android 7.1 the wifi icon does not only show the signal strength by the well known circular four bar image, but also underneath it there are two tiny arrows, one pointing up and the other one pointing down. They are used to indicate correspondingly the activity for the upload and the download. This feature although seems cool at first can be very distracting at times, when you read for example. My question is can you disable the animation? Ideally just remove two tiny arrows and only leave out the curved signal bars just like it looks on iOS for example.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just tweak the arrows from the UI. But you can disable the notification icon.

Since you’re on Marshmallow, first enable System UI Tuner by long pressing the Settings icon in the pull-down notification shade for 5 seconds. Then go to

`Settings->System UI Tuner->Status bar->Disable WiFi.`

Done.

Comment: This must be another question, but regardless of how long I press the gear icon the ui tuner does not show up? Htc u11

Comment: @exebook Seems HTC has blocked access to system UI Tuner. If youre root you can download https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.pruss.tuner to enable it. Also there's a video for unrooted phones https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-O5t6j29tjc&feature=youtu.be might be helpful. Try it out